# PHP import CSV containing single quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql, import-csv

I am trying to import a CSV file containing single quotation marks into the text. And each time, MySQL gives me an error. How could I avoid this type of error?

Here is one of the texts that causes problem:

*Sam Capra, agent de la CIA basé à Londres, échappe à l'explosion de son bureau grâce à un appel de sa femme Lucy. Mais cette dernière, enceinte, disparaît et Sam est tenu responsable de l'attentat par la CIA.*

and here is my SQL query:

```
 $sqlInsert = "INSERT into products_details (`product_title`,`product_price`, `product_image`, `product_gallery`,`product_description`, `meta_value`, `stock`, `weight`, `active`)
 values ('" . $column[2] . "','" . $column[21] . "','uploads/" . $column[0] . ".jpg','" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[22] . "','" . $json . "','" . (int)$column[15] . "','" . $column[20] . "','" . (int)$column[23] . "')";
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples. Applying this technique will take care of all your quoting issues.

Comment: Where is you CVS file download code? You can write your own function to escape quotation mark in the string.

Comment: And you already got some bad practice answers down here, so don't escape the string, don't replace comma with any other character and so on. Just use prepared statements (Follow the links in the first comment)

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes I use a prepared before inserting via mysqli :)

Comment: Using a prepared statement is not sufficient. You need to use a prepared statement with bound parameters.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I decided to follow your advice and use PDO. And everything works perfectly. Thank you very much for the tips and links.

Answer (score 0):

notice tgat you have single quotes *inside* the text
you should escape the string

I assume that $column[22] is the variable containing the text that you gave in the example, and let's say that $conn is your mysqli object
Then this line shouls be added to your code, before you're insert string creation

```
$column[22] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $column[22]) ;
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works perfectly!

Comment: Do not use this technique, it is outdated and provides insufficient protection against SQL injection.

Comment: @AlexHowansky ok I see. I will try to see something else in this case :) Thank you for the advice